# Strange behavior when drawing on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas

Basically, I'm trying to create a grid spanning multiple canvases, but I get strange behaviour on the first and last one. The stroke color and spacing is changed. I don't see how it could happen. Here is the relevant code, follow the link to see it in action. (the site is work in progress)
http://www.gjar-po.sk/~hudak9c/test3/

```
var canvasCount = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas").length;

if (canvasCount > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < canvasCount; i++) {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[i];

    if (canvas.getContext("2d")) {
      var can = canvas.getContext("2d");

      can.beginPath();

      for (var x = 5; x < 640; x += 20) {
        can.moveTo(x, 0);
        can.lineTo(x, canvas.height);
      }

      for (var y = 5; y < canvas.height; y += 20) {
        can.moveTo(0, y);
        can.lineTo(canvas.width, y);
      }

      can.lineWidth = 1;
      can.strokeStyle = "#000";
      can.stroke();
    } else {
      alert("getContext fail");      
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: I managed to fix the problem. It was caused by me (obviously) setting the width and height of the canvas through style.width and style.height, not through canvas.width and canvas.height, which made them stretch/shrink from their default dimensions instead of resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set width and height to the canvases by tag attributes `width` and `height` like this:

```
<canvas width="640" height="50">
```

Not by `style` attribute. It is very important. Because when you set `style` attribute and point there `width` and `height` properties, then your canvas with default real `width` and `height` just stretches to your new sizes.